# Why is it that I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous>"

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a gallery that uses navdots as the user swipes panels, but for some reason I'm getting an error in this line of my code:

```
    navdots[ad.fs.currentPoint].classList.add('active');
    ad.logger.track('cta_swipe', {
      o: 'slide' + ad.fs.currentPoint
    });
```

What could possibly be causing this? Also, here's my navdots setup:

```
    <ul id="navdots">\
      <li class="point active"></li>\
      <li class="point"></li>\
    </ul>\
```

...and here's the function that first bit of code is nested in:

```
setupSlider: function() {
      var navdots = ad.expandable.findAll('.point');
      navdots = [].slice.apply(navdots);

      var fs = new Flipsnap(ad.expandable.find('#slider'), {document: ad.expandable.el.contentDocument});
      ad.fs = fs;

      var leftArrow = ad.expandable.find('#leftArrow');
      var rightArrow = ad.expandable.find('#rightArrow');

      leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(fs.currentPoint === 0) {
          fs.moveToPoint(fs._maxPoint);
        }
        else {
          fs.toPrev();
        }
      });
      rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(fs.currentPoint === fs._maxPoint) {
          fs.moveToPoint(0);
        }
        else {
          fs.toNext();
        }
      });
       navdots.forEach(function(dot, index) {
        dot.addEventListener('click', function() {
          fs.moveToPoint(index);
        });
      });
      ad.fs.element.addEventListener('fspointmove', function() {
        navdots.forEach(function(dot) {
          dot.classList.remove('active');
        });
        navdots[ad.fs.currentPoint].classList.add('active');
        ad.logger.track('cta_swipe', {
          o: 'slide' + ad.fs.currentPoint
        });
      });
    },
```

Comment: is `ad.fs.currentPoint` < 0 or > 1 or not even a number? - try `console.log(ad.fs.currentPoint); console.log(navdots[ad.fs.currentPoint])` - does the output look correct?

Comment: It does, actually. But still getting the error.

Comment: what does it log to the console that looks correct

Comment: 0 or 1. Which seems right because I only have two slides. So the first would be 0, and so on.

Comment: And the other console output

Comment: also, what does `console.log(navdots);` output

Comment: The other was NaN

Comment: And console.log(navdots), spits out: [li.point, li.point]
0
:
li.point.active
1
:
li.point
length
:
2

Comment: I'm assuming you're adding these console.log's just before the fatal line

Comment: clearly the navdots array isn't an array of actual LI elements

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the question with a snippet?.
The error is relative to the object from which you call the classList function is not being defined correctly. Normally, it is a mistake to have forgotten to specify table indexes if you get the object from an array or index values that do not correspond to any object in the table. For example if you have 4 values and you ask for it 5. Do the snippet so in step you review the code being attentive to this detail. He usually comes around. Although what really fails as it indicates is the definition of the object.